# Display view on complete timer - react native

Tags: react-native

### What am i trying to achieve

we have scheduled appointments.with runs with timer. when the scheduled time comes(timer is 0 minutes),

### what am i expecting to get out

we need to display some exiting view with the text 'Join Chat'.

here is my code.

```
import Avatar from '@components/Avatar/Avatar';

import AppText from '@components/AppText/AppText';
import Timer from '@components/Timer';
import useGlobalStyles from '@app/theme/useGlobalStyles';
import { parseDateFormat } from '@utils/date_utils';
import { fontPixel, pixelSizeHorizontal } from '@utils/pixel_size';
import getStyles from '../styles';
import { useSelector } from '@hooks/.';
import { consultService } from '@features/consult/services';
import { selectAppointments } from '@features/appointment';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Patient } from '@services/patient/types';
import fonts from '@app/theme/fonts';
import { AppThemeColors } from '@app/theme';

import { NavigationParams } from '@app/navigation/types';
import { ROUTES } from '@constants/routes';
import waitingRoomService from '@services/waitingRoom/waitingRoom.service';
import AnyDoctor from '@app/assets/images/any_doctor.svg';
import { WaitingRoom } from '@services/waitingRoom/types';
import { Appointment, AppointmentType } from '@services/appointments/types';
import { checkAppointmentStatus, getUserFromAppointment } from '@utils/appointment_helper';
import { selectSelectedPractice } from '@features/practice';
import { selectActivePatient, selectPatients } from '@features/patient/usePatient';
import { selectDefaultBillingCard } from '@features/billing';
import appointmentTexts from '@constants/texts/appointment';
import patient from '@features/patient';

type AppointmentDisplay = {
    doctorName?: string;
    type: AppointmentType;
    date: Date;
    consultInviteId?: number;
    consultationId?: number;
    waitingRoom?: WaitingRoom;
    appointment?: Appointment;
    patient?: Patient;
    avatarUrl?: string;
};

export type PatientLatestAppointmentProps = {
    onRefresh: () => void;
    onSwitchModalRequired(appointment: Appointment, selectedUser?: Patient): void;
};

const PatientLatestAppointment = ({ onSwitchModalRequired, onRefresh }: PatientLatestAppointmentProps) => {
    const { colors }: { colors: any } = useTheme();
    const { navigate } = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<NavigationParams>>();
    const appColors: AppThemeColors = colors;
    const styles = getStyles(colors);
    const globalStyles = useGlobalStyles();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [initialised, setInitialised] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [consultInviteLoading, setConsultInviteLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
    const [consultAppointment, setConsultAppointment] = useState<AppointmentDisplay>();
    const [appointmentDisplay, setAppointmentDisplay] = useState<AppointmentDisplay>();

    const { activePatient, subPatients } = useSelector(selectActivePatient);
    const { selectedPractice } = useSelector(selectSelectedPractice);
    const patients = useSelector(selectPatients);

    const appointments = useSelector(selectAppointments);
    const appointmentsLoading = useSelector((state) => state.appointment.isLoading);
    const defaultCard = useSelector(selectDefaultBillingCard);

    const getPatient = (patientId: number) => {
        return patients.find((p) => p.id === patientId);
    };

    const onPress = useCallback(async () => {
        if (!appointmentDisplay) {
            return;
        }

        if (!defaultCard) {
            navigate(ROUTES.payment.payment_method, { isMedicationFlow: true });
        } else if (appointmentDisplay.consultInviteId) {
            try {
                setIsLoading(true);
                const invite = await consultService.acceptInvite(
                    appointmentDisplay.consultInviteId,
                    activePatient.id!,
                    appointmentDisplay.waitingRoom?.id
                );
                navigate(ROUTES.chat, { consultInviteDetails: invite });
            } catch {
                // [TODO:DEV] handle error
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        } else if (appointmentDisplay.waitingRoom) {
            navigate(ROUTES.waiting_room_details, {
                waitingRoom: appointmentDisplay.waitingRoom,
                defaultCard,
            });
        } else if (appointmentDisplay.appointment && selectedPractice?.id) {
            const status = checkAppointmentStatus(
                appointmentDisplay.appointment,
                activePatient.id!,
                selectedPractice.id!
            );
            if (!status) {
                navigate(ROUTES.CancelAppointmentScreen, {
                    appointment: appointmentDisplay.appointment,
                    defaultCard,
                });
                return;
            }

            if (onSwitchModalRequired) {
                let switchToUser: Patient | undefined;
                if (status != 'fromOtherCentre') {
                    switchToUser = getUserFromAppointment(appointmentDisplay.appointment, subPatients);
                }

                onSwitchModalRequired(appointmentDisplay.appointment, switchToUser);
            }
        }
    }, [navigate,appointmentDisplay,activePatient?.id,selectedPractice?.id,subPatients,onSwitchModalRequired,defaultCard,]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (appointmentsLoading || consultInviteLoading) {
            setAppointmentDisplay(undefined);
        } else if (consultAppointment) {
            
            setAppointmentDisplay(consultAppointment);
        } else {
            const latestAppointment = appointments[0];
            if (latestAppointment) {
                

                const latestAppointmentDate = moment(latestAppointment.appointmentDate);
                if (latestAppointmentDate.diff(new Date(), 'days') <= 7) {
                    setAppointmentDisplay({
                        date: latestAppointmentDate.toDate(),
                        type: latestAppointment.appointmentType,
                        doctorName: `${latestAppointment.doctorFirstName} ${latestAppointment.doctorLastName}`,
                        patient: latestAppointment.patient,
                        appointment: latestAppointment,
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }, [
        appointmentsLoading,
        consultInviteLoading,
        consultAppointment,
        appointments,
        selectedPractice,
        activePatient.id,
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (appointmentsLoading || !initialised) {
            setInitialised(true);

            async function init() {
                if (!activePatient) return;

                setConsultInviteLoading(true);
                setConsultAppointment(undefined);

                let waitingRoom: WaitingRoom | undefined;
                try {
                    waitingRoom = await waitingRoomService.getLatestByPatientId(activePatient.id!);
                } catch {
                    // ignore
                }

                const patient = waitingRoom?.patientId ? getPatient(waitingRoom.patientId) : undefined;

                try {
                    const invite = await consultService.getInvite();
                    let avatarUrl: string | undefined;
                    if (invite.doctorAvatarId) {
                        
                        
                    }

                    setConsultAppointment({
                        type: AppointmentType.Telehealth,
                        doctorName: `${invite.doctorFirstName} ${invite.doctorLastName}`,
                        consultInviteId: invite.id!,
                        consultationId: invite.consultationRoomId,
                        waitingRoom: waitingRoom,
                        date: new Date(invite.createdDate!),
                        patient: patient,
                        avatarUrl,
                    });
                } catch {
                
                    if (waitingRoom) {
                        setConsultAppointment({
                            type: AppointmentType.Telehealth,
                            waitingRoom: waitingRoom,
                            date: new Date(waitingRoom.createdDate!),
                            patient: patient,
                        });
                    }
                }
                setConsultInviteLoading(false);
            }

            init();
        }
    }, [appointmentsLoading, activePatient?.id]);

    if (!appointmentDisplay) {
        return null;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.containerPaddingWhite}>
                <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={colors.primaryBlue} size="small" />
            </View>
        );
    }

    const PatientSectionContainerLayout = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => (
        <View style={styles.containerPaddingWhite}>
            <View style={styles.boxShadow}>{children}</View>
        </View>
    );

    const Description = () => (
        <View>
            <AppText variant="overline" style={{ color: colors.placeHolder }}>
                {appointmentDisplay.patient &&
                    `${appointmentDisplay.patient.firstName} ${appointmentDisplay.patient.lastName}`}
            </AppText>
            <AppText variant="overline" style={{ color: colors.placeHolder }}>
                {appointmentTexts[appointmentDisplay.type] || 'Appointment'}
            </AppText>
            <AppText variant="overline" style={{ color: colors.placeHolder }}>
                {`${parseDateFormat(appointmentDisplay.date).fullDate}`}
            </AppText>
        </View>
    );

    const RightItem = appointmentDisplay.consultInviteId
        ? () => (
                <View
                    style={{
                        alignItems: 'flex-end',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                    }}
                >
                    <AppText
                        variant="body"
                        style={{
                            color: colors.primaryBlue,
                            fontFamily: fonts.medium,
                        }}
                    >
                        Join chat
                    </AppText>
                    <FeatherIcon
                        name="log-in"
                        style={{ paddingVertical: 5 }}
                        size={pixelSizeHorizontal(20)}
                        color={appColors.primaryBlue}
                    />
                </View>
          )
        : () => (
                <View style={styles.patientAppointMentRightIcon}>
                    <View style={[styles.appointmentRightItemContainer]}>
                        <View style={styles.flexJustifyCenter}>
                            <Timer
                                style={{ fontSize: fontPixel(12) }}
                                until={appointmentDisplay.date}
                                format={['D', 'H', 'M']}
                                onCompletion={onCompleteTimer}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.flexJustifyCenter}>
                        <Icon name="right" size={fontPixel(16)} style={styles.mt11} />
                    </View>
                </View>
          );

    const onCompleteTimer = () => {
        if (appointmentDisplay?.appointment?.appointmentType === AppointmentType.Telehealth) {
            //need to include here
        } else if (appointmentDisplay?.appointment?.appointmentType === AppointmentType.FaceToFace) {
            
            onRefresh();
        }
    };

    return (
        <PatientSectionContainerLayout>
            <Fragment>
                <View style={styles.subAvatarContainer}>
                    {appointmentDisplay.doctorName ? (
                        <Avatar name={appointmentDisplay.doctorName} url={appointmentDisplay.avatarUrl} />
                    ) : (
                        <AnyDoctor />
                    )}
                </View>
                <List.Item
                    onPress={onPress}
                    rippleColor="transparent"
                    style={[globalStyles.flex1, globalStyles.p0]}
                    titleStyle={styles.flexCenterStart}
                    title={() => (
                        <AppText variant="bodyMedium">
                            {appointmentDisplay.doctorName
                                ? `Dr ${appointmentDisplay.doctorName}`
                                : 'First available doctor'}
                        </AppText>
                    )}
                    description={() => <Description />}
                    right={() => <RightItem />}
                />
            </Fragment>
        </PatientSectionContainerLayout>
    );
};

export default PatientLatestAppointment;`
```

need to display 'Join Chat' part when timer is complete.onCompleteTimer is already called.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.